# Joined Reports with 2 unrelated child objects

Tags: lightning, master-detail, custom-reports, joined-reports

I'm trying to create a joined report with a custom object (object A) as the base. It is the Master in two Master-Detail relationships (Object B and Object C). Object B and Object C are NOT related.

When I create a report using Object A and then try to add either Object B or Object C, I get the following error: "Choose a different report type. This one has no common fields with the other report types in this joined report."

I assumed that since each of the child objects has a reference to Object A's id, this would not be a problem. What am I missing here?

Comment: where you able to solved this?